# Is there a collective term for theorems, lemmas, properties, corollaries?

Tags: terminology

I wonder whether there exists a collective term for theorems, lemmas, properties and corollaries?

Comment: When developing an algorithm I feel the final algorithm is your result and not the properties/lemmas/... that precede it.

Comment: Do you mean proposition rather than property?

Comment: When would you use proposition instead of property?

Comment: You would not. But property does not really fit in with the other terms. Proposition does.

Comment: This question seems more on topic at english.stackexchange.com, though I suspect it would be a little too vague even there. If anything, I think “theorems” actually does work as a collective term here (excluding properties, as mentioned by others, though).

Comment: In mathematical logic, all of these (except properties) are called 'theorems'. More generally, 'sentences'. The difference between a theorem and a sentence is that a theorem is actually true (or provable, depending on the context). A sentence may or may not be true.

Answer (score 3):

The distinction into *axiom*, *observation*, *remark*, *proposition*, *lemma*, *corollary*, *example*, *theorem*, *fundamental theorem* according to importance of the statement or easiness of proof is rather a matter of taste (except for axioms maybe).
Jointly, all these are typically called *theorems*, that is provable statements (of a particular theory).

Comment: Clearly, an axiom is deducible, thus a theorem. But in a formal theory, an axiom *is* distinct from a theorem, in that it is recorded as such. In addition, axiom schemes (and/or proof rules---depending on terminology) have not been mentioned.