# Can you have a corollary of an axiom?

Tags: soft-question, proof-theory

Can you use the word 'corollary' for an easy consequence of an axiom, or is it a word reserved for consequences of theorems?

Also, if it is not a word for an easy consequence of an axiom, is there a word (or phrase) that would be appropriate in that situation?

Comment: No "standard" terminology; you can see the post: [whats-the-difference-between-theorem-lemma-and-corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463362/whats-the-difference-between-theorem-lemma-and-corollary).

Comment: I looked there, but I wondered if they may only have said 'a corollary is an easy consequence of a theorem' because it did not occur to them that it could also follow from an axiom.

Comment: According to dictionary, a [corollary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corollary) "is a proposition inferred immediately from a proved proposition with little or no additional proof". *Formally* an axiom is a theorem (is a theorem with a $1$-line lenght proof). Thus...

Comment: Well, in math logic we have axioms, proofs, and theorems; the distinctions between corollary, lemma, proposition, and theorem don't enjoy any formal definitions. It would seem odd to have a corollary to an axiom, just because people don't usually do that, but if you're the independent "go my own way" sort, why not! Otherwise, call it a proposition.